# Scope email issue on google login codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api, google-signin

Sorry, I am repeating my question again because I don't get any answer but I hope today I will. Now, I have created google login using CodeIgniter which is working fine it takes me on login page when I click on `Google image` after filling up all details when I click on next button then it takes me out from google login to my website and URL look likes

`https://example.com/google_login?code=4/lQDGQ6sJog3ZrLKGJtn-VVD3rbzgJl16jMLUrk6wzBIbsu-F6mjlLuPOepeobDLmFYqQL25jo4iAgI9ZnVKTSVY&scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`

which show me 404 error but if I remove

`&scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` from URL then it shows me all information of clients.

Please help me

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to stack we do not open duplicate questions just because we did not get the answer we needed on the original question.   We improve the original question in hopes of getting an answer.   You only waited 21 hours it can take days before someone spots your question that can help.  Reading this may help you improve your question [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried without adding route in routes.php and it works (the removed string is putted inside `$this->input->get('scope')`).

You may need to add an route in routes.php. If route match google response url, link it to your controller.

Comment: please look at once this is my same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300464/scope-email-issue-on-google-login-codeigniter?noredirect=1#comment93483499_53300464

Comment: @Bruce I don't know why but that url works with me [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/OSRw1kN.png)